# Probability that of having exactly two boys

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> If in a family of 3 children, there is at least 1 boy, what is the probability that there are exactly 2 boys among the children?

**My attempt:**

I calculated all the possibilities of the family by having at least one boy,

$1$B and $2$G - $2*2$$*$$3 \choose 1$
$2$B and $1$G - $2$$*$$3 \choose 1$
$3$B - $1$

That sums up to 18.

So, the probability of having exactly 2 boys,

$$\frac{2*3}{18}$$

But the answer given is $\frac{3}{7}$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your error is that you are calculating the probability that there will be exactly two boys, but you are requested to calculated the conditional probability that there will be exactly two boys, given the information that there is at least one boy.

Comment: 1B and 2G has 3 possibilities, not 6 (by symmetry it has to match 2B 1G), and if you make this change you get 14 as the denominator hence the correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $B$ be the number of boys.

What you are looking for is

$$P(B=2 | B\geq 1) = \frac{P([B=2]\cap [B\geq 1])}{P(B\geq 1)}=\frac{P(B=2)}{P(B\geq 1)}$$

Assuming $B$ follows a binomial distribution of parameters $p=1/2$ and $n=3$, you have $$P(B=2) = \frac{\binom{3}{2}}{2^3} = \frac{3}{8}$$ and $$P(B\geq 1) = 1 - P(B=0)= 1 - \frac{\binom{3}{0}}{2^3} = \frac{7}{8}$$

which leads to $3/7$ as expected.

Comment: This is indeed the calculation that the OP was looking for. However, it does not answer his question as he put it. This is because the universe of families of three children contains only four possibilites: No boys, exactly one boy, exactly two boys, and exactly three boys. Out of this universe, the universe of at least one boy contains three possibilties, out of which only one has the property of "exactly two boys". Therefore the answer to the question, as it is outlined in the yellow box, must be $1/3$, not $3/7$. Differentiating between BBG and GBB, answers a different question.

Comment: @uniquesolution Your logic is incorrect. Just because the universe has four possibilities, that does not imply all those possibilities are equally likely. The problem likely intended the genders of the children to be independent, so Florian’s analysis is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It can sometimes help to draw a tree diagram and eliminate the branches not compatible with the information.

1 child:
B or G

2 children:
BB, BG, or GB, GG

3 children:
BBB, BBG, BGB, BGG, GBB, GBG, GGB, GGG

The last family GGG is the only one not containing at least 1 B, so there are 7 possible families.

The number containing exactly 2 boys in that 7 families is equal to 3, $p=3/7$.